# socket.io-redis Typescript error

Tags: typescript, redis, socket.io, definitelytyped

I tried using `@types/socket.io-redis` like so:

```
import { Server as HttpServer } from 'http';
import socketIo, { Socket } from 'socket.io';
import redis, { RedisAdapter } from 'socket.io-redis';

export default function setupWebsocket(server: HttpServer) {
    const io = socketIo().listen(server);
    io.adapter(redis(process.env.REDIS_URL));

    const adapter: RedisAdapter = io.of('/').adapter;    // Error here
}
```

At the section where the *Error here* comment is, I got a red underline at the `adapter` variable with the error:

> Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'RedisAdapter'.
>
> Property 'uid' is missing in type 'Adapter'.

Can anyone help me fix this issue? I'm quite new to Typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct behaviour, type of `io.of('/').adapter` is `Adapter`. Fact that you assigned specific implementation(`RedisAdapter`) of interface(`Adapter`) don't change property type, as later you might change to different implementation of `Adapter`.

Possible solution might be to assign adapter directly after creation

```
import { Server as HttpServer } from 'http';
import socketIo, { Socket } from 'socket.io';
import redis, { RedisAdapter } from 'socket.io-redis';

export default function setupWebsocket(server: HttpServer) {
    const io = socketIo().listen(server);
    const adapter: RedisAdapter = redis(process.env.REDIS_URL);
    io.adapter(adapter);
    //... more code here
}
```

Other solution is to cast to desired type

```
const adapter: RedisAdapter = io.of('/').adapter as RedisAdapter;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. thank you very much for the answer **and** the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try casting using `as`:

```
const adapter: RedisAdapter = io.of('/').adapter as RedisAdapter;
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question... but I found this post before reading the docs :-)

According to the documentation for v6 of `@socket.io/redis-adapter`, you should import `createAdapter` function to initialize the adapter

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis-adapter#typescript

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';

const io = new Server(8080);
const pubClient = new RedisClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this version   socket.io @4.5.4,the issue is with the newer version of socket.io@4.6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).